# MySQLdb: connect to MariaDB via socket

Tags: python, mariadb, mysql-python

I've got a fresh MariaDB installation, without password.
Connecting via `mysql` works for the root user, without password and without any additional parameters.

```
$ sudo -i root
$ mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Server version: 10.2.21-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
```

But connecting to socket using python MySQLdb library fails:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) 
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock')
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Is it a problem for MariaDB vs. MySQL compatibility? Can anybody reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

It was not a passwordless root account. It was one with a default password.
`mysql` just read it automatically from /etc/my.cnf.d/ folder

```
[client]
socket   = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = ...
```

To debug `mysql` CLI-behaviour vs. python MySQLdb behaviour, you can run

```
mysql --no-defaults
```

which already reproduced the behaviour for me, so I continued with:

```
mysql --no-defaults --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql --no-defaults --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --user=root
```

then got the idea to dig deeper into /etc/my.cnf.d/ folder.